# Angular and dynamically added CKEditors break

Tags: angular, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm having an issue with dynamically added CKEditors rendred via `NgFor` with `angular@2.0.0-alpha.44`.

[Live demo is available here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/wHPV4rOTVK4lLTEZHxif?p=preview)

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'textarea'
})
class CKEditor {
    constructor(_elm: ElementRef) {
        CKEDITOR.replace(_elm.nativeElement);
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
})
@View({
    directives: [NgFor, CKEditor],
    template: `
      <div *ng-for="#item of items">
        {{ item }}: <textarea>{{ item }}</textarea>
      </div>
      <button (click)="addItem()">Add</button>`
})
class AppComponent {
    items = ['default_0', 'default_1'];

    constructor() {
        this.addItem();
    }

    addItem() {
        var id = 'ckeditor_inst_' + this.items.length;
        this.items.push(id);
    }
}
```

You can see three CKEditors that work correctly. Then click "Add" button at the bottom and it breaks the last CKEditor in the container in a way that you can even write to it and if you press any toolbar button it throws:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelection' of undefined`.

It's interesting that only the last CKEditor is broken, the other two work. It seems like Angular2 somehow manipulates with the last element which breaks the CKEditor.

I remember using the same way of adding new CKEditors in `angular@2.0.0-alpha.35` and I think it worked there but maybe I just didn't notice. Version [`angular@2.0.0-alpha.47` is the same](http://plnkr.co/edit/6YnDmqU7P6bX4Sy0P9fg?p=preview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in `beta-15`, see:

http://plnkr.co/edit/X5whPqDhLS6RjTR2N8hT?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

Your integration uses [Classic](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_framed) CKEditor because of `wysiwygarea` plugin, which enables editing in an `<iframe>` (i.e. to avoid CSS collision with the webpage).

The drawback of such implementation is that once you detach (and re–attach) such `<iframe>` from DOM (like Angular does each time you add a new `item`), its internal `document` gets "broken". By broken I mean that `document.body` is loaded from scratch, losing your content, CKEditor bootstrap code, JS references, etc. and eventually making the whole editor instance useless.

So the problem lies in the way this view is being rendered:

```
@View({
    directives: [NgFor, CKEditor],
    template: `
      <div *ng-for="#item of items">
        {{ item }}: <textarea>{{ item }}</textarea>
      </div>
      <button (click)="addItem()">Add</button>`
})
```

And I see three solutions to this problem:

- Clean solution: Force Angular to not re–render the entire `items` collection when a new item is added.
- Tricky soluction: Use [Inline](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_inline) CKEditor, which works in `<div contenteditable="true" />` div instead of `<iframe>...<body contenteditable="true" /></iframe>` and is immune to mutations in DOM.
- Lazy and slow solution: Stick to current integration but destroy all `CKEDITOR.instances` (`instance.destroy()`) before a new item is added and then re–initialise them `CKEDITOR.replace()`.